# Recovering data from not initialized volume

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, raid-1

I had two disk RAID1 volume configured through RST option ROM. Couple of days ago I've reset BIOS to default configuration and lost RAID1, disk were transformed to Non-RAID and appeared as separate in OS. I tried to reverse this through RST ROM, but it warned me I couldn't do so without losing data. So I foolishly tried to do it through the IRST desktop application without backing up anything, I've created RAID1 volume and now it appears as not initialized volume and I afraid to do further steps. 
What I need to do to recover my data?

Comment: If you stopped and asked us before you did anything, data recovery might have been possible, your actions were destructive to your data.

Comment: If it was so destructive I wouldn't ask, but I've checked it with some freeware "recovery tool" and all my files are there, and they are not deleted and not overwritten by anything. IRST just created a RAID Volume, no formatting. Initialization would destroy it. I just need to a way to turn them into two separate initialized disk again.